# Sufficient condition for a system to have memory

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals, system-identification

This is for a black box system which is not LTI and for which we have no input output expression, but we have some examples of sample inputs and corresponding outputs.

I believe in this situation, we can only know for sure if the system has memory if, for some value of $t=t0$ or for a discrete system $n=n0$, we have $x1(t0)=x2(t0)$ producing the output values $y1(t0) \neq y2(t0)$ (and an analogous reason for the discrete time case).

Otherwise, there is no way to tell whether it has memory or not.

I have never read this criteria written anywhere so I wanted to know if there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  A system with memory can certainly generate $y1(t0) = y2(t0)$ for $x1(t0) = x2(t0)$. It can also generate $y1(t0) \ne y2(t0)$.  A memoryless system cannot generate anything else than $y1(t0) = y2(t0)$ for the given input. So you might need another condition or constraint to check to tell if the system has memory. Hmm. Perhaps it's sufficient, then to have $y1(t0) \ne y2(t0)$ to indicate that the system has memory. However, it's not necessary.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $x_1(t_0)$ and $x_2(t_0)$ ? You cannot apply two different inputs at the same time. How would you construct this experiment.

Comment: @Hilmar how so? We the same value of $t0$

Comment: see my updated comments.

Comment: @Hilmar I understand what you mean now. If this was a real system with real time I couldn't. This question appeared in the context of a homework problem (not posed like this, it was to say if the system had memory and I wanted to get some more general properties), and as such I actually can have the same value for the time variable. In terms of how to construct this experiment, the system is a matlab function provided by my professors.

Comment: That still doesn't work., I think There is no such thing as $y_1(t_0)$ or $y_2(t_0)$ There is only one point in time $t_0$ and at this point in time it can only have one output value $y(t_0)$. Basing a criteria on the assumption that you can magically rewind time and do it again with a different input feels very problematic to me. You wind up with a criteria that cannot be applied to a real system. You would also have to define what types of behavior the system displays with respect of time reversal.

Comment: @Hilmar ok I understand if t is actually time. But there is no reason for it to actually be time. Maybe this would have been a better question for Math Stack Exchange then but this is just something abstract, with no regard to reality. I do appreciate your input: the reason why I never saw this written anywhere is probably because it is not very useful then, not because it is wrong.

Comment: I think it is a very interesting question to ponder. The logical problem arises because you are required to observe the system twice. That requires you to specially define how the system can or cannot change between these two observations. Your Matlab code implicitly implies that the system is time reversible, i.e. if you rewind time (or any other x-axis variable) and run the same input you would you get the same output as before. That's not necessarily the case: they their may be systems that are not time reversible.

Answer (score 2):

**What is a System without Memory? - Static Systems**

The concepts to assess are of *Static System* and *Time Invariant Systems*

Remember the definition of Static System, a *Memoryless System*, whose present output $y(t)$ depends on the present input $x(t)$ only, and the current time:

$$
y(t)=h(t,x(t))  \\  \forall t, \forall x(t)
$$

Also remember, a Time Invariant Static System will in addition not depend on time, only on the inputs $x$

$$
y(t)=h(x(t))  \\  \forall x(t)
$$

Examples:

- A Time Invariant Static System example would be an Amplifier, with characteristic curve $y(t)=h(x(t))$.
- A Time Variant Static System example would be a Modulator $y(t)=\cos(\omega t)h(x(t))$.

**What is a System with Memory? - Dynamic Systems**

Both of the previous examples are Memoryless, in the sense they do not have any State, History or Memory related to the inputs $x$. We can agree the oscilator has states, but no states related to the input.

Anything else, this is, any Non Static System, will be a *Dynamic System*. As you see, this is a strongly loose way to define Dynamic Systems, but unfortunately, the most *canonical*.

From there, you must remember a Dynamic System is the formal definition for a System with States, History or Memory, again, independently of the structure of these States.

**Which would be a *Basic Brick* of Memory? - A base for Dynamical Systems**

The most basic Dynamic System brick could be a **Delay Trigger**, which is always 0, but outputs $x(t_0)$ at $t=t_1>t_0$. This would be the most basic in the sense of values taken.

As you can check:

- This is not a Static Time Invariant or Variant system,
- $y(t)$ depends on $x(t_0)$ for $t > t_0$, hence has Memory,
- Is Causal for $t_0<t_1$, Non Causal for $t_0>t_1$ (and... Time Variant Static for $t_0=t_1$).

$$
y(t)=x(t_0)\delta(t-t_1)
$$

As you can check, if you integrate these Delay Triggers in $t_0$, you obtain the standard **Delay** System, which is also Dynamical.
$$
y(t)=\int_{t_0} x(t_0)\delta(t-t_1) dt_0 = x(t-dt)
$$

Also, following this principle, just integrating our basis set i.e. applying a dot product in the function space, you can recover all Dynamical Systems. For example, a **First Order LTI** System will born, just dot product between our Delay Trigger brick and an exponential function with decay $s$, nesting an additional integral over $t_1$:
$$
y(t)=\int_{t_0} \int_{t_1} e^{-s (t_1-t_0)} x(t_0)\delta(t-t_1) dt_1 dt_0 \\
    =\int_{t_0} x(t_0) e^{-s(t-t_0)} dt_0 = x(t)*e^{-st}\\
$$